# Hide buttons in Datables for non-authorized users with Spring Security

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-security, datatables, jsp-tags

I need to hide buttons in Datables for non-authorized users.

In plain jsp I was used spring security tags to hide elements for non-authorized users.

E.g. hide delete button:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"> <a href="delete/${author.id}">Delete</a></sec:authorize>
```

But in jquery datatables, buttons are come from inner javascript config. And I can't use spring security tags.
E.g. delete button in DataTables:

```
"buttons": [
{
    text: "Delete",
    action: function (e, dt, button, config){
        //button onClick here
    }
}
]
```

Comment: If you can get the authorization status into a JavaScript variable, you can set `buttons` based on the variable. I don't know any JSP or Spring.

Comment: @thirtydot, yes I can get authorization variable in js, but what I should do next? How I can check this variable in Datatables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
var authStatus = true; //your auth status variable from JSP

var buttons = [];

if (authStatus) {
    buttons = [
        {
            text: "Delete",
            action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
                //button onClick here
            }
        }
    ];
}

$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: buttons,
});
```

You could instead write it inline with a ternary operator, but it won't be as clear.